# How to solve IIS authentication error which says There was an error while performing this task?

Tags: iis-8

While setting up IIS for our application, the authentication is getting errored out. The error is : There was an error while performing this operation.
Filename: \?\E:\inetpub\wwwroot\Web\web.config[The error is attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lesjw.png)

Tried few iis settings

Comment: To dig further into this error, people need to see the contents of that web.config file. You cannot hide it and ask for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that some configuration section in web.config is not recognized by IIS. So please check if you are missing any IIS functional modules, such as URL rewrite module, ASP.NET core module, CORS module, etc. You can verify this by commenting out the contents of Web.config. Until the error disappears, then gradually reduce the number of tags that are commented out until you find the source of the problem.

If you are running an asp.net core site in iis, you need to install .net core hosting bundle and .NET Core Runtime. You can download it from this [link](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core) according to your version. If the Hosting Bundle is installed before IIS, the bundle installation must be repaired. [Run the Hosting Bundle installer again after installing IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle).

Comment: Thank you , installing the rewrite module solved the problem.